# How to localize a file in WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, resources

I need to do localization in WinRT. I have a resource file named *resource.resw* and I have given name, value and comment. I tried using the resource loader to call the localization, but it didn't work. What is the proper syntax?

```
var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
var str = loader.GetString("farewell");
```

Comment: Please provide your code. Consider improving your question after your read this: [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
            var str = loader.GetString("farewell");                                                         Now i need to call the resource.resw file intead of calling the string

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing `GetForCurrentView`() on your first line.

```
var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();
var text = loader.GetString("Farewell");
```